# Is there a tool for easily creating a GIF/video with a morph transition between two images?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, animation

I have found the following video, which shows a transition effect which is based on a sort of morph-based interpolation between two images:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/f07/proj_final/www/amichals/one.mpg

Is there a tool for easily creating a GIF (or a video) with a similar effect (so no fading), starting from two images (start and end)?

Comment: Hi Vito Gentile, Welcome to GD.SE! What operating system? Free or paid?

Comment: @AndrewH I prefer something free working on Windows if possible. But if this is not available, anything else would be fine too.

Comment: Morphing software used to be all the rage back in late 1990's. Today you will find that most serious animation/fx software can do this out of the. So for example After Effects can do it. Also all serious 3D packages can also do this as their entire facial animation systems depend on being able to do this, so having a dedicated morph tool has not made much sense in ages (hell even path apps like Mathematica and Matlab can do this), but software recommendations are not on scope.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for your answer. Which website of the StackExchange community is more appropriate for graphic software recomendations like mine?

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer other than what you've found, then I would ask over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://principleformac.com/ or After Effects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a free web site for doing this (that, however, allows only for producing low quality GIFs):

https://3dthis.com/morph.htm

Another software is [Morpheus Photo Morpher](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqjK6K87jNAhWCnRoKHeT7BXIQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.morpheussoftware.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNGjp3iLq_95G7AZdqQp4PPa2zZoaA&sig2=mk3YiznkPAKNYBD5FmGbVQ), which is not free but seems to be more powerful and equally easy to use.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: 3dthis does not let you download the video (even after sneakily forcing you to sign up) and Morpheus looks like it hasn't been updated in a decade. Would not recommend either of them